# Django Cart System - Delete from Cart

Tags: html, jquery, python-3.x, django

I am developing an e-commerce application using Django and HTML. Right now, I am working on deleting an item from my cart.

**views.py in Cart app:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .cart import Cart
from SeniorProjectApp.models import MenuItem
from django.http import JsonResponse

def cart(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart_items = cart.cart.values()
    name = cart.cart.values
    total_price = sum(float(item['price']) for item in cart_items)

    return render(request, "cart/cart.html", {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total_price': total_price, 'name': name})


def cart_add(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        item_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
        item = get_object_or_404(MenuItem, id=item_id)
    

        cart.add(item=item)
        cart_quantity = cart.__len__()

        response_data = {'qty': cart_quantity}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)


def cart_delete(request, item_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    item = get_object_or_404(MenuItem, id=item_id)
    cart.remove(item)

    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Item removed successfully'})
```

**cart.py in Cart app:**

```
class Cart():
def __init__(self, request):
    self.session = request.session

    cart = self.session.get('session_key')
    if 'session_key' not in request.session:
        cart = self.session['session_key'] = {}
    
    self.cart = cart

def add(self, item):
    item_id = str(item.id)

    if item_id in self.cart:
        self.cart[item_id]['quantity'] += 1
    else:
        self.cart[item_id] = {
            'name': item.name,
            'price': str(item.price),
            'quantity': 1
        }

    self.session.modified = True

def delete(self, item):
    item_id = str(item.id)

    if item_id in str(item.id):
        self.cart[item_id]['quantity'] -= 1
        if self.cart[item_id]['quantity'] == 0:
            del self.cart[item_id]
        self.save()


def __len__(self):
    return len(self.cart)
```

**cart.html in Cart app:**

```
{% extends 'SeniorProjectApp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h2 style="color:white">Your Cart</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="color:white">Item</th>
                <th scope="col" style="color:white">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           {% for item in cart_items %}
           <tr style="color: white">
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>${{ item.price }}</td>
            <td>Quantity: {{ item.quantity }}</td>
            <td>
            <td> 
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark flex-shrink-0" type="button" style="color: white;" 
                  value="{{ item.id }}" id="delete-cart">Remove
                </button>
            </td>    
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p style="color:white">Total Price: ${{ total_price }}</p>
 </div>
 <script>
    $(document).on('click', '#delete-cart', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var productId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url 'cart_delete' item_id %}',
            data: {
                item: productId,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                action: 'delete'
            },
            success: function(json){
            },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
            } 
        });  
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py in Cart app:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('add/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    path('delete/<int:item_id>/', views.cart_delete, 
                                         name='cart_delete'),
    path('update/', views.cart_update, name='cart_update'),
]
```

So, the issue i seem to be running into is in the following line:

```
url: '{% url 'cart_delete' item_id %}',
```

I keep getting a NoReverseMatch error at /cart/ that says:

**Reverse for 'cart_delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/delete/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/\Z']**

I've tried making the item_id = 0 but then I get a 404 not found error on my url.

I am pretty new to Django and Web development altogether so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you show the urls.py for `cart_delete` ?

Comment: I just added the url.py file

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the ajax call. You are trying to send `item_id`, which is probably undefined.

Change the `url: '{% url 'cart_delete' item_id %}',` line to

```
url: '{% url 'cart_delete' 0 %}'.replace('0', productId),
```